# É possível remover a opção todos os arquivos no explorador de arquivos?

Tags: html

Com `accept` posso setar quais formatos são aceitos.

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/png">
```

Ele filtra, porém no explorador ainda é possível selecionar todas os arquivos como na foto.

[image: explore]

É possível remover essa opção e deixar somente a que quero?

Comment: pega o nome do arquivo, e corta a string os ultimos 4 caracteres (que será a extensao do arquivo), ai basta ter um array de extensoes que sao aceitas, e verificar se a extensao está no array, se estiver cadastra, se não, avisa ao usuario que o arquivo n foi enviado

Comment: Essa validação já está feita, porém só queria saber se é possível eliminar o 'todos os arquivos' do select no explorador, se eu não me engano, já vi essa opção desabilitada na hora de escolher os arquivos.

Comment: @FelipeDuarte você pode ter visto essa opção indisponível ou desabilitada em um programa específico feito em outra linguagem. No navegador, pelo menos nos maiores não existe essa limitação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando apenas HTML **Não é possível**.

Isso porque janela de pesquisa do arquivo na tag **`input file`** é do Sistema Operacional. O atributo **`accept`** comunica o Sistema Operacional o tipo ou tipos de arquivos aceitos ***inicialmente***, ajudando o usuário a encontrar os arquivos aceitos, mas nada impede que a opção "Todos os arquivos" seja selecionada.

Somente programas sendo executados diretamente no sistema operacional e com permissão para explorar arquivos no computador conseguem fazer esse tipo de limitação conforme pode ver na imagem abaixo:

[image: Filtro tipo de arquivo efetuado pela aplicação]

> Se sua aplicação conseguisse se comunicar com alguma outra sendo
>   executada no Sistema Operacional isso seria possível.

Answer (score 1):

É possível apenas setar o padrão de início... que vem marcado, mas se quiser, dá pra mudar a extensão do arquivo na hora de explorar arquivos, assim como está na tua imagem.

Mas dá para receber os arquivos e tratar na hora de cadastrar ou realmente guardar os arquivos, fazer a verificação de extensão

Answer (score 1):

A opção utilizada apenas deixa os tipo desejado marcado como padrão. Não é possível remover essa opção (pelo menos até hoje).

Eu creio que a melhor coisa a se fazer no caso de não querer arquivos de determinados tipos é validando através do servidor (usando NodeJS, PHP ou outras linguagens, por exemplo).